# Gitlab with external secrets (Vault token)

Tags: gitlab

We use GitLab Community Edition v16.4.1 and try to pull secrets from Vault with this simple GitLab CI, but it's complaining about not having secrets key.

What could be the issue? CE version does not have secrets option?

```
stages:
  - prep
  - build

job-prep:
  stage: prep
  id_tokens:
    VAULT_ID_TOKEN:
      aud: https://vault_server.com
  secrets:
    DB_PASSWORD:
      vault: gitlab/test/service/DB_PASSWORD@kv
      file: false
      token: $VAULT_ID_TOKEN
  script:
    - echo $DB_PASSWORD

job-build:
  stage: build
  needs:
    - job-prep
  script:
    - echo $DB_PASSWORD
```

> Pipeline error: `This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: jobs:job-prep config contains unknown keys: secrets.`

Answer (score 1):

> secrets keyword is available only in paid Premium or Ultimate.